# I can't build c++ files anymore

Tags: c++, include, mingw, iostream, include-path

I think i deleted some files i shouldn't and now when i try to build files in Sublime Text it says "g++ is missing" and in VS Code it says "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath..." and "cannot open source file 'iostream'...". How can i fix this?

Comment: You may want to reinstall your compilers and their environments.

Comment: Is going through the recycle bin or equivalent on your platform and restoring deleted files an option?

Comment: No, deleted them permanently and don't remember which ones

Comment: Reinstall g++ by whatever method you installed the first time.

Comment: Well, if you gotta reinstall the toolchain, consider [installing a good toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

Answer (score 0):

If you broke your installation, you need to reinstall what you broke.

If you just need a GCC toolchain and don't want the hastle of installing, you could get a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/ and extract it to a folder.

If you do this to a separate folder you can leave your existing installation untouched, but you will need to point the VS Code settings to it.